# How to extract only integer part of string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract only integer, and I come up with this regex.

```py
[-\d][^.]
```

`[-\d]` -> it finds all integer even negative one 
`[^.]` -> I think it stops at the `.` but failed
This one grab after dot part.
`3.14 -> 14` It should only extract `3`

My test cases are,

```py
Input -> Expected Output
3.14  -> 3
      -42  -> -42
-789word -> -789
789word -> 789
789.89word -> 789
-789.89word -> -789
```

**EDIT**
My test case always starts with either of these three cases.
1. white space
2. digit
3. negative sign 
How can I improve my regex pattern?

Comment: I remember seeing this question before right?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yup. I improved the question to meet the requirement. Do you see anything wrong with my question? I can improve it!

Comment: Perhaps using a capturing group? `^[^\d\r\n]*(-?\d+)`  https://regex101.com/r/UmsAtu/1

Answer (score 2):

It might be as easy as

```
^\s*-?\d+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/O18Yz9/2).

Comment: What about second example?

Comment: Very simple. I thought `^` means `starts with`. So `^-?` means, whether it starts with `-` or not. Is it correct? How does it stop before `.` ?

Comment: as @OlvinRoght said, it does not work if there is white space

Comment: @jayko03: Pretty much. THe `^` means that the whole expression should start at the beginning of the string. `\d` always stops before a `.` as it only includes digits.

Comment: @Jan, it will fail on "abcd 123.456". It's better to not stick to line start in my opinion.

Comment: @OlvinRoght that is a good point! But It will always start with `white space` or `negative sign` or 'just digit`. I will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) with simple pattern `"-?\d+"`:

```
import re

strings = ("3.14", "      -42", "-789word", "789word", "789.89word", "-789.89word")
for s in strings:
    match = re.search("-?\d+", s)
    print(f"{s} => {match.group()}")
```

Quote from docs:

> Scan through *string* looking for the first location where the regular expression *pattern* produces a match.

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
dd = "-3.14afr" 
re.findall(r'-?\d+', dd)[0]
## the output is 
-3
```

Comment: There's `re.search` which search for first match.

Comment: "findall" was the first thing that comes to my mind